# Is there a function/library/technique to help generate correct/non-redundant contexts for TH generated instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, template-haskell

Is there a a function that can take a given context/`[Pred]` and simplify it?

Some examples for what I mean by that:

- If the context contains `Eq [a]` replace it with `Eq a` (because it implies the more complicated constraint)
- If the context contains `Eq Int`, filter that out
- Remove duplications

Use case: I've implemented [TH functions](https://github.com/lamdu/hypertypes/blob/05ad1ba5b918c3a17ea1f922538cec36153996e0/src/Hyper/TH/Functor.hs#L18) to derive instances, and these instances in turn use things like `fmap` so they require context, and I want to produce instances that will not generate redundant constraint warnings.

I already made a [`simplifyContext :: [Pred] -> Q [Pred]`](https://github.com/lamdu/hypertypes/blob/05ad1ba5b918c3a17ea1f922538cec36153996e0/src/Hyper/TH/Internal/Utils.hs#L180) helper to do this, but as this sounds to me like a common need, I expect this possibly already exists in some library but I've tried to find it and haven't. Or if it doesn't exist perhaps that's because there's a simpler technique that I'm missing..

Comment: Similar to (but not a duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091316/detecting-redundant-constraints-in-haskell